# I'm having trouble with the .innerHTML not working properly

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I cant get the "if" part to work, thus not outputting the text Test0 or Test1 to my "Test" div after I press either of the links. I have checked for any error messages, which there are none of. I also added the changing color to check if it was the event listeners that were the problem, but that worked fine. So my only problem is that I can't get the text to output.

```js
var testEl = document.querySelector("#test");
var menyEl = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < menyEl.length; i++) {
  menyEl[i].addEventListener("click", byttInfo);
}
function byttInfo(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "ikke_aktiv") {
    for (var i = 0; i < menyEl.length; i++) {
      menyEl[i].className = "ikke_aktiv";
    }
    e.target.className = "aktiv"
  }
  if (e.target.value === 0) {
    testEl.innerHTML = "Test0"
  } else if (e.target.value === 1) {
    testEl.innerHTML = "Test1"
  }
}
```

```css
.innpakning {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #708790;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.loddrett_meny {
  display: flex, block;
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.loddrett_meny a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.loddrett_meny a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.aktiv {
  background-color: #3cb500;
}

.ikke_aktiv {
  background-color: #555;
}

.innhold,
#test {
  flex: 6;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #a6d4a3;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="innpakning">
  <div class="loddrett_meny">
    <a class="aktiv" value="0">Kapittel 20</a>
    <a class="ikke_aktiv" value="1">Kapittel 20.1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `e.target.value === "0"){` Are you sure the if-clause is working?

Comment: `value` is a custom attribute for `a` element, it is not reflected to the properties of the element.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use quotes around values or convert them to `Number`

```
if(e.target.value === "0"){
    testEl.innerHTML = "Test0"
}else if(Number(e.target.value) === 1){
    testEl.innerHTML = "Test1"
}
```

Comment: also dont you think it should be testEl.innerText = "Test0"

Comment: Yes, it's safer then innerHTML since it's inset only text and prevent injections.

Comment: (SOLVED)It still won't work, even after turning it into number and using innerText instead of InnerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Adding on what Abdulah Proho said: You can't add the `value` attribute to `a` tags, so it's discarded and `e.target.value`. You may use data attributes for this:

```js
var testEl = document.querySelector("#test");
var menyEl = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < menyEl.length; i++) {
  menyEl[i].addEventListener("click", byttInfo);
}
function byttInfo(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "ikke_aktiv") {
    for (var i = 0; i < menyEl.length; i++) {
      menyEl[i].className = "ikke_aktiv";
    }
    e.target.className = "aktiv"
  }

  if (e.target.dataset.value === "0") {
    testEl.innerHTML = "Test0"
  } else if (e.target.dataset.value === "1") {
    testEl.innerHTML = "Test1"
  }
}
```

```css
.innpakning {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #708790;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.loddrett_meny {
  display: flex, block;
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.loddrett_meny a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.loddrett_meny a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: 0.75s;
}

.aktiv {
  background-color: #3cb500;
}

.ikke_aktiv {
  background-color: #555;
}

.innhold,
#test {
  flex: 6;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #a6d4a3;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="innpakning">
  <div class="loddrett_meny">
    <a class="aktiv" data-value="0">Kapittel 20</a>
    <a class="ikke_aktiv" data-value="1">Kapittel 20.1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

e.target.value is undefined. Due to anchor tags usually not having value attribute. The 'a' elements don't have the data prototype for value.

You should try getting the value using:

```
e.target.getAttribute('value')
```

Also while comparing try using:

```
e.target.getAttribute('value') === '0'
```

Given the value you get from getAttribute function is a string the value getting compared with should also be a string.

Answer (score 0):

The following works I have tested it as a snippet. Trying copying this entirely and replace it with your js. you need to use the getAttribute method to get the value.

```
var testEl = document.getElementById("test");;
var menyEl = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < menyEl.length; i++) {
  menyEl[i].addEventListener("click", byttInfo);
}
function byttInfo(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "ikke_aktiv") {
    for (var i = 0; i < menyEl.length; i++) {
      menyEl[i].className = "ikke_aktiv";
    }
    e.target.className = "aktiv"
  }
  if (e.target.getAttribute("value") === "0"){
    testEl.innerText = "Test0"
  } else if (e.target.getAttribute("value") === "1") {
    testEl.innerText = "Test1"
  }
}
```